# Remove Plank from Alt+Tab switcher

Tags: application-switcher, plank

My dock, Plank, is in the Alt+Tab switcher. It's very annoying and serves no purpose. How do I remove it?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with reinstalling Plank.

```
sudo apt-get remove plank
sudo apt-get install plank
```